# Parameterizing diode value in SPICE

Tags: spice, ltspice

I have a bunch of diodes of the same type on a schematic in LTSpice. How do I parameterize the diode's type (Value) so that I can change it in one place and it would change it for them all?

The .PARAM statement doesn't seem to be supporting literals, so I cannot use something like

```
.PARAM DiodeValue=NSPW500BS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround using the `.SUBCKT` dot command. Here is an example circuit:

[image]

And here is the output:
[image]

In short you should create a subcircuit with two terminals whose only internal component is the diode you want.

The SPICE code:

```
.subckt MyDiode A K
D A K 1N4148
.ends
```

defines a subcircuit called `MyDiode` with two terminals named `A` and `K` (these names are local to the subcircuit definition). `.ends` ends the definition. The code inbetween is regular SPICE code which says that a diode `D` is placed between (local) nodes `A` and `K` and that diode has a `1N4148` SPICE model.

The `.lib standard.dio` is required to load the models (`1N4148`) used inside the subcircuit. If the models of the diodes you want to use are not in the standard LTspice part libraries you must put the complete path in the `.lib` directive (see LTspice guide for details).

Note that you have to change the default attributes of the diodes you usually place on the schematic, as shown in this image:

[image]

Note that the `Prefix` must be changed from `D` to `X` (to tell LTspice the part is a subcircuit and not a standard diode) and the `Value` attribute must be the name of the subcircuit (here `MyDiode`).

From now on, if you want to change the "implementation" of `MyDiode` parts, it is sufficient to change the subcircuit definition, as you can see in the image below, where I changed it to use an `1N4007` model:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since I discovered a relevant undocumented feature of LTspice, I post this new, possibly better, answer.

***Disclaimer**: this was an edit to [another answer I posted in this thread before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/176443/29434). Since then I discovered the accepted practice on SE sites is to post additional answers if they are logically independent (see [this Meta.EE.SE question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/splitting-own-muliple-solution-answer)).*

It turns out that a simpler method exists, thanks to an undocumented feature of LTspice I recently discovered. The `.model` directive allows a format where you can specify that the model you are defining is *A Kind Of* some other model (*AKO*):

```
.model MyDiode AKO: 1N4007
```

Therefore the previous simulation setup can be simplified in this way:

[image]

In this case you don't need to change the advanced attributes of the diodes as before. You only need to specify `MyDiode` as the value of the part:

[image]

That feature is documented [here](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29) in LTspice Yahoo group WIKI and allows a couple other tricks, such as changing some parameters of the existing model, or defining a model with a purely numeric name, which allows using it in a `.step` directive to step through different models (all having custom numeric model names).